# Pulley joint bounce out of view and slows world

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

json string is parsed and values passed to appropriate Java classes.
`no-args` constructor is called for each object as I'm using `Gson`.
I then call `pulley.init(world);` to actually add object to world.

The problem is that the objects are parsed and loaded into Box2d world.
The `Pulley` is present, there are 2 boxes with a line joining them.
When scene is loaded the pulley is falling from sky, slowly.
Then it suddenly jumps up out of sight and the entire world becomes horribly slow.
Is this setup correctly for the `Pulley` joint? I dont know why joint flies out of sight and causes this degradation in perf.

json object definition ..

```
"pulleys":[
    {
        "anchorA_Low": 2.0,
        "anchorB_Low": 2.0,
        "anchorA_High": 10.0,
        "anchorB_High": 10.0,
        "ratio": 2.0,
        "shapeA": {
            "position": {
                "x": -30.0,
                "y": 10.0
            },
            "angle": 0.0,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0,
            "bodyType": "DYNAMIC",
            "density": 5.0,
            "friction": 0.0,
            "restitution": 0.0,
        },
        "shapeB": {
            "position": {
                "x": -10.0,
                "y": 10.0
            },
            "angle": 0.0,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0,
            "bodyType": "DYNAMIC",
            "density": 5.0,
            "friction": 0.0,
            "restitution": 0.0,
        }
    }
]
```

Java class for a `Pulley` object.

```
public class Pulley extends Joint{

    private Vec2 groundAnchorA;
    private Vec2 groundAnchorB;
    private Vec2 anchorA;
    private Vec2 anchorB;   
    private float anchorA_Low;
    private float anchorB_Low;
    private float anchorA_High;
    private float anchorB_High;
    private float ratio;

    public Pulley() {}

    public void init(World world){

            Body bodyA = getShapeA().setupShape(world);
            Body bodyB = getShapeB().setupShape(world);

            IAEdge edge = new IAEdge(bodyA.getPosition(), bodyB.getPosition());
            edge.init(world);

            anchorA = new Vec2(bodyA.getPosition().x, bodyA.getPosition().y + anchorA_Low);
            anchorB = new Vec2(bodyB.getPosition().x, bodyB.getPosition().y + anchorB_Low);

            groundAnchorA = new Vec2(bodyA.getPosition().x, bodyA.getPosition().y + anchorA_Low + anchorA_High);
            groundAnchorB = new Vec2(bodyB.getPosition().x, bodyB.getPosition().y + anchorB_Low + anchorB_High);

            PulleyJointDef pulleyDef = new PulleyJointDef();
            pulleyDef.initialize(bodyA, bodyB, groundAnchorA, groundAnchorB, anchorA, anchorB, ratio);
            world.createJoint(pulleyDef);
    }

    public Body setupShape(World world){

        PolygonShape blockShape = new PolygonShape();
        blockShape.setAsBox(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = blockShape;
        fixtureDef.density = getDensity();
        fixtureDef.friction = getFriction();
        fixtureDef.restitution = getRestitution();

        BodyDef bodydef = new BodyDef();
        bodydef.type = BodyType.valueOf(getBodyType());
        bodydef.position.set(getPosition().x, getPosition().y);
        bodydef.angle = getAngle();

        Body body = world.createBody(bodydef);
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        return body;
    }
}
```

Java class to encapsulate Box2d's EdgeShape.

```
public class IAEdge {

    private Vec2 pointA;
    private Vec2 pointB;

    public IAEdge(){}

    public IAEdge(Vec2 pointA, Vec2 pointB){

        setPointA(pointA);
        setPointB(pointB);
    }

    public Body init(Level level) {

        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        Body ground = level.createBody(bd);

        bd.position.set(
            new Vec2(
                ((pointA.x + pointB.x) / 2), 
                (pointA.y + pointB.y) / 2));

        EdgeShape shape = new EdgeShape();
        shape.set(
            new Vec2(pointA.x, pointA.y), 
            new Vec2(pointB.x, pointB.y));

        ground.createFixture(shape, 0.0f);

        return ground;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `jbox2d`, fixed in `2.3.1-SNAPSHOT`